# Office-js. Caught an exception when replacing

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I am developing an extension for Word and from time to time, when using the replace method `.insertText(replacement, 'Replace')`, I catch an error. Immediately after it, without reloading the page, I cannot change the text

```
main.js:1 error RichApi.Error: Cannot read property 'Dqb' of null
at new n (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:26:301595)
at n.i.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:26:363168)
at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:26:361273
```

----FULL REPLACE METHOD----

```
replace = async (replacement: string, issue: IIssue, segments: Array<Segment>) => {
    const context = await this.getText();
    if (typeof context === 'string') {
        let indexPosition = findIndexPosition(context, issue, segments);
        const issueText = issue.segment.substr(issue.from, issue.until - issue.from);
        return Word.run(async (context) => {
            const body = context.document.body;
            let searchResult = body.search(issueText.trim());
            let fonts;
            context.load(body);
            context.load(searchResult);
            await context.sync()
                .then(() => {
                    fonts = searchResult.items[indexPosition].font;
                    context.load(fonts);
                })
                .then(context.sync)
                .then(() => {
                    searchResult.items[indexPosition].insertText(replacement, 'Replace');
                    searchResult.items[indexPosition].font.set(fonts)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error('error', err);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more of your code. Also try using the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab tool.

Comment: @RickKirkham I added full replacement method

Comment: Can I see the line where you load the Office JavaScript library? It's probably a `<script>` tag in your home page.

Comment: @RickKirkham <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>

Comment: Try loading https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.debug.js and see if you get a more informative error message.

Comment: @RickKirkham I started using this library, but it didn't give me more information

Comment: If you are using the debug version, then the error message should not have short aliases like "Dbq" or "n". It should have the full object and property names. What does the error message look like now?

Comment: @RickKirkham 
error RichApi.Error: Cannot read property 'Dqb' of null
    at new RuntimeError (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.debug.js:12918:36)
    at RequestContext.ClientRequestContext.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.debug.js:16096:24)
    at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.debug.js:16001:43

Comment: Try to reproduce the error in [Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab).